# raw input analog in Bottle

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

I can't figure out how to make raw_input() in Bottle framework.

```
for idx, d in enumerate(student):
        for ids, s in enumerate(student):
            if d['Name'] == s['Name'] and idx != ids:
                print d,idx
                l=raw_input('input number to delete')
                student.pop(int(l))
    for m in student:
    for k in olympiad:
      if m['Name']==k['Name']:
                this.append(k)
```

If I return a template instead of raw_input() i'll lose all other actions. And i don't want to write this action in console.

Comment: I am a bit confused.  Bottle is an HTTP framework, raw_input is for reading from STDIN.  How would you send to STDIN over HTTP?

Comment: Well in web frameworks we use textbox to get input from the user not `raw_input`.

Comment: @sberry i can send it using POST. i don't quite understand how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottle is a web-framework and therefore all of its input and output happen through a web server. This means that if the web server even has a standard input, it is definitely not connected to any web browser, so `raw_input` is of no use in a Bottle WSGI environment.

The most ordinary means of getting user input under WSGI is through a POST browser request. For that, you should learn about [Bottle forms](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#request-data).

Comment: so you say i should somehow redirect user to another template and post variables from that template?